# Replace a string from a vector of string C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, replace

I have a vector of string constructed using:

```
vector<string> names;
names.push_back("Gates");
names.push_back("Jones");
names.push_back("Smith");
names.push_back("Gates");
```

I want to replace "Gates" with "Bill", for every occurrence of "Gates".
For this the easiest solution I know is to use the replace function from algorithm and use it as:

```
replace(names.begin(), names.end(), "Gates", "Bill");
```

But I am getting following error:

```
 parameter type mismatch:incompatible types 'const char (&)[6]' and 'const char[5]'.
```

I can solve it using implicit type casting like this:

```
replace(names.begin(), names.end(), "Gates", (const char (&)[6]) "Bill");
```

Can anyone explain what this error is, and better way to solve it or better way to do it. Or why do we need this type casting.

Comment: In C++17 you can do `replace(names.begin(), names.end(), "Gates"s, "Bill"s)` which looks a lot better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The old/new value parameters in `std::replace` share the same type.

For example, the function might look like:

```
template<class ForwardIt, class T>
void replace(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, const T& old_value, const T& new_value);
```

[Stolen from here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace), not that it's that significant.

`"gates"` is a `const char[6]` but `bill` is a `const char[5]`, which is why you get the error about being unable to convert it.

You could either wrap each string literal in `std::string()` or just use the unary `+` operator to decay each literal to a `const char*`.

```
replace(names.begin(), names.end(), +"Gates", +"Bill"); //shorter
replace(names.begin(), names.end(), std::string("Gates"), std::string("Bill")); //clearer
```

---

I'm pretty sure `((const char (&)[6]) "Bill")` violates strict aliasing, so I'd avoid casting between array types like that.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest (assuming some `using std;`)

```
 replace(names.begin(), names.end(), string{"Gates"}, string{"Bill"});
```

since the type of `"Gates"` is `char[6]` (decayed to `char*`) and you want to replace `std::string`-s (not `char*` !!).